# Omiting brackets for named arguments inverts order

Tags: groovy, named-parameters

There is nothing in http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_named_arguments that would explain this behaviour.

```
def foo(String a,Map b) { println "a: ${a}; b: ${b}" }
foo('a',b : 'c')
```

Results in an error: `No signature of method: Script1.foo() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String) values: [[b:c], a]`

```
def foo(String a,Map b) { println "a: ${a}; b: ${b}" }
foo('a',[b : 'c'])
```

Prints out: `a: a; b: [b:c]`

Swapping the order of arguments in definition also makes it compile:

```
def foo(Map b,String a) { println "a: ${a}; b: ${b}" }
foo('a',b : 'c')
```

Prints out `a: a; b: [b:c]`

Is this a bug in groovy or is it some unexpected "groovy goodness"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually undocumented Groovy behavior. When using named parameters with additional parameters, Groovy expects that `Map` parameter that stands for named parameters is the first parameter of the method if you skip square brackets in map definition. If we analyze the bytecode generated by compiler we will see that following line:

```
foo('a',b : 'c')
```

is expressed by following Java code:

```
CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
return var1[1].callCurrent(this, ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[]{"b", "c"}), "a");
```

As you can see the order of parameters passed to `callCurrent()` method is reversed comparing to the one you have defined when calling `foo()` method. It's a bit confusing, especially that adding square brackets explicitly changes generated bytecode:

```
foo('a', [b: 'c'])
```

is expressed by following Java code:

```
CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
return var1[1].callCurrent(this, "a", ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[]{"b", "c"}));
```

---

It got explained briefly in "*Programming Groovy 2"* book by Venkat Subramanian :

> ```
> class Robot {
>    def type, height, width
>
>    def access(location, weight, fragile) {
>        println "Received fragile? $fragile, weight: $weight, loc: $location"
>    }
> }
>
> robot = new Robot(type: 'arm', width: 10, height: 10)
> robot.access(x: 30, y: 20, z: 10, 50, true)
> robot.access(50, true, x: 30, y: 20, z: 10)
> ```
>
> *"This `access()` method receives three parameters, but if the first parameter is a `Map` we can float around the map's key-values in the argument list. (...) Although the kind of flexibility in the `Robot` example is powerful, it can get confusing, so use it sparingly. (...) We can avoid confusion like this by explicitly naming the first parameter as `Map`:"*
>
> ```
> def access(Map location, weight, fragile) { /* .. */ }
> ```

Btw, IDE like IntelliJ IDEA helps understanding the order of parameters:

[image]

Now, if I only set `Map fragile` it will alert that there is something wrong with our method invocation:

[image]

Also, using `@groovy.transform.TypeChecked` and `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` annotations help catching such problems at the compile time. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! The only thing I don't get is: what is the point? I don't see the Robot example solving any problems, certainly nothing "powerful".

Comment: Well, I would love to know the reason behind it. I can only guess that requiring `Map` to be the first parameter in named parameter use case was introduced in the early days and never got changed. I have checked `3.0.0-alpha-3` Groovy version and this behavior remains unchanged. Fixing it would break backward compatibility and it sounds like a pretty rare case, so most probably no one ever bothered.

Comment: Btw, upcoming Groovy 2.5.4 release will have updated documentation on named arguments - https://github.com/apache/groovy/pull/812 Thanks for reporting this, credits go to you as well! :)

Comment: Great, thanks. Hopefully it can save somebody a bit of head scratching